# Simple query taking long time in MySQL 

Tags: mysql

I must be overseeing something, but I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    `Poster`, Round(Sum(If((`Date`>=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 Month) And `Date`<CURDATE()),1,0))/DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 Month)),0) AS `statistics`
FROM `forenposts`
GROUP BY `Poster`
ORDER BY `statistics` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This takes roughly 15 seconds in a database with more than 1.5 million entries.

Is there an easy way to optimize it or is the If function just taking so long?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query? I removed some constant calculations out of the query, as operation with every row tends to be very slow. Also, I would use constant, not CURDATE() function inside the query, so DB server can optimise it. I can't try it, let me know if it works and I can explain it with more details.

```
SET @CURDATE = CURDATE(); 
SET @DATEADD = DATE_ADD(@CURDATE,INTERVAL -1 Month);
SET @DATEDIFF = DATEDIFF(@CURDATE,@DATEADD);

SELECT
    `Poster`, 
    Round(Sum(If((`Date`>=@DATEADD And `Date`< @CURDATE), 1, 0)) / @DATEDIFF,0) AS `statistics`
FROM `forenposts`
GROUP BY `Poster`
ORDER BY `statistics` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thank you, this reduced the speed to 3.75 seconds. I am not sure, if it's possible to get it lower than that.

Comment: Btw, I am not sure, if the where optimization is correct, is it? I remove it from my answer, can you try this version, if it returns the mase results?

Comment: The results are the same!

I wanted to convert this into PHP code, but I couldnt get it to work.
Here is the code I use:
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SET @CURDATE = CURDATE(); SET @PREVDATE = DATE_ADD(@CURDATE ,INTERVAL -". $timeperiod . "); SET @DIFF = DATEDIFF(@CURDATE, @PREVDATE); SELECT   `Poster`,   Round(Sum(1 / @DIFF), 0) AS `statistics` FROM `forenposts` WHERE  `Date`>=@PREVDATE And `Date`< @CURDATE GROUP BY `Poster` ORDER BY `statistics` DESC LIMIT 5;");

Comment: Btw, do you have an index on the Date column? I am not sure, if index will be applied in this case, but it could also help. I can't help you with PHP, new question would be better.

Comment: I dont have an index on the date column, the thing is, the date values arent really unique.

Comment: @user1626443: Values in a column don't have to be unique to allow indexing. A non-unique index is quite a normal thing for a table to have (just FYI).

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question. Yeah, the column is actually indexed, but there is no increase in efficiency.